# Series of trigonometric system

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For $0<b<1$, I was asked to show that
$
\text { If } f \in L^{2}[0,1], \text { then }
$
$
f(x)=b \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle f, e^{2 \pi i b n x}\right\rangle e^{2 \pi i b n x}
$. My attempt is let $g(x)=f(\frac{x}{b})$ for $[0,b]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then $g$ can be represented by orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$:$
e_{n}(x)=e^{2 \pi i n x}
$ and then pull back from $g$ to $f$. However I think I missed some part since I didn't get the lead coefficient $b$ of $
f(x)=b \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle f, e^{2 \pi i b n x}\right\rangle e^{2 \pi i b n x}
$. Also how to show this series converges undonditionally? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Have you checked the constant in change of variable? More precisely, $$
g(x) = \sum_n \left(\int_0^1 g(x) \cdot e^{-2\pi inx}\, dx \right)\cdot e^{2\pi inx}.
$$
Now, in computing $\int_0^1 g(x) \cdot e^{-2\pi inx}\, dx = \int_0^b f(x/b) \cdot e^{-2\pi inx}\, dx$, one would use change of variable $y=x/b$, so the integral is equal to $$
\int_0^1 f(y) \cdot e^{-2\pi in(by)}\, bdy.
$$
Did you include the $b$ in front of $dy$ in your computation?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the map
$$
T:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1/b],\quad f\mapsto \sqrt{b}f\circ \varphi \\
\varphi :[0,1]\to[0,1/b],\quad x\mapsto bx
$$
for $b\in(0,1)$ then $T$ is an isometric homeomorphism. Then setting $g:=\mathbf{1}_{[0,b]}\frac1{\sqrt{b}}f\circ \varphi ^{-1}$ its easy to see that if $f\in L^2[0,1]$ then $g\in L^2[0,1]$ also and

$$
 g=\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z }\langle  g,e_k \rangle e_k\quad \text{ in }\,L^2[0,1]\iff T g=\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z }\langle T g,Te_k \rangle Te_k\quad \text{ in }\,L^2[0,1/b]\tag1
$$
Now note that $Tg=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}f$ and $Te_k=Te^{2\pi i kt}=\sqrt{b}e^{2\pi i k bt}$ so substituting in the RHS of $\mathrm{(1)} $ we get

$$
\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}f=b\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z }\langle \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}f,e^{2\pi ik bt} \rangle e^{2\pi ik bt}\quad \text{ in }\,L^2[0,1/b]\tag2
$$
Then $\mathrm{(2)} $ holds in the sense of point-wise convergence in $L^2[0,1]$.